# [16.04]Laptop behaves awkwardly when I'm running ubuntu

Tags: suspend, power-management, hp, battery, overheating

This may seem strange. But last month I bought a new laptop from HP and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 along side windows 10.
From a month now, I'm observing quite unnecessary things going on and a bit strange.

1. The battery drains too quickly as compared with windows. I know that Ubuntu is not that power efficient but it lasts not more than 1 hour with general usage while on windows I get around 3.5-4 hours of battery life.
2. When I suspend it for like 20 minutes and I come back, it's on fire! God knows what happens but my laptop will be sickly overheating. When it is suspended then why the hell it starts heating up?
3. Fans spinning too fast like I'm on some heavy usage or doing 4k editing even when I'm only reading Quora on chrome. Strange, isn't it ?

My laptop is rocking a 6th generation core i7 with 12 GB of memory and Nvidia GTX 950M.

What can I do regarding these power management/overheating issues?

Comment: I think some newer processors (such as the Intel Skylake series) do not have great power management support under Linux yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Which graphics driver do you use? Check it in "System Settings" → "Software & Updates" → "Additional drivers".

Answer (score 0):

A lot of reasons could be the culprit, and honestly it could be an unlucky combination all of the reasons combined. Every situation is unique. Here's what I would do:

Always - A good practice is to make sure your PC is currently up to date, run this command:

```
apt-get update
```

and then this command:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Then I'd wait to see if that fixed the issue.

1 - I'd run the command `top` to see what processes and resources are being commonly used. I'd also have `top` running before it suspends so I can see it first thing when it awakens. I'd research each one to make sure its useful to my usage and needs.

2 - I'd also go through the Startup Applications List to see what apps are auto-starting. There shouldn't be but a few things running. Again, I'd research each one to make sure its useful to my usage and needs.

3 - I'd double check the settings in the Power Menu as well as the Brightness & Lock settings too. Could be a bad combination of settings.

4 - I'd also check Bluetooth and wireless settings, if left on they could easily draw from battery. Again, could be a bad combination of settings.

5 - Remember to save and exit from any apps you have running before suspending your laptop.

6 - I'd, personally, try a new fresh install with a new download and a freshly burned CD. I'd go so far as to try Lubuntu or Xubuntu just to see if they have better results with the Hardware.

Good Luck!